# Maintaining Cordova offline/online events when loading remote content

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm building a Cordova wrapper for a remotely-hosted website, currently targeting the Android platform. I want the app to navigate to the locally-hosted no-network error page when there is no connectivity, and to the remote site when connectivity is detected.

When the app launches, I bind offline & online check events using `cordova-plugin-network-information`:

```
    bindEvents: function() {
       document.addEventListener('offline', app.onOffline, false);
       document.addEventListener('online', app.onOnline, false);
    }
    onOffline: function() {
       app.navigate('#error');
    },
    onOnline: function() {
       window.open('http://example.com', '_self');
    }
```

This works during app start-up, and when the app view is on the `#error` page. If I am on the `#error` page and the device gains connection, then it loads the external page.

However, once I've load the external website, the `offline/online` events no longer fire.

- Is this because the app's JS is no longer loaded in this WebView, on account of having navigated to that external URL?
- If so, how can I leave the app's JS loaded while also loading remote content? Is this a job for iframes? A subview? Loading all the cordova & plugin on the remote server? Other?

Comment: Have you whitelisted the external URL you want to navigate to? Like so `<access origin="http://example.com" />`. The [cordova wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser) says that only whitelisted URLs will be loaded in the cordova WebView even though you call open with the '_self' parameter, others will be loaded in the InAppBrowser.

Comment: Yes, I've whitelisted the external URL. It looks to me like it is loading inside the cordova WebView- there's no URL bar, it's inside the same application tab, and the "back" button takes the user directly back to the local app. Should the app JS still be present if it is in the same cordova WebView?